# What is the right way to use Lock?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project on **spring-boot**, but without tomcat(I don't need it). I communicate with other services via webSocket (but that's not important either). **Java 11**.

I have the following scenario.
Let's imagine that there are 3 classes. **TestManager, TestClient** and a common one where the previous two classes are injected, let's call it **TestService**.

**TestClient** has a **send()** method and **TestManager** class has a **refresh()** method. And also in the **TestService** class there is an **execute()** method, it is marked with spring-boot annotation **@Async** (i.e. the method is executed **asynchronously**).

Now I need to implement the following logic - depending on some conditions, I need to either immediately execute the **send()** method from the **TestClient** class, or **first execute the refresh()** method from the **TestManager** class. The **refresh** method takes a **long time** to execute and should be executed by **only one process**.

Ideally, when executing the refresh method - all other methods should wait for the result of this method execution by the very first process and go straight to the send() method of the TestClient class.

I've been thinking for a long time how this could be done most efficiently in asynchronous code, I'm thinking about the **Observer pattern** but it seems to be too much. Can I be helped by a regular ReentrantLock?

The problem is that the other processes should queue up and wait for the refresh method to be executed by the first process, and then they should not go to execute refresh, but go straight to execute send().

Example Scheme:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {

  private final TestClient client;
  private final TestManager manager;

  @Async
  public void execute(){
    // When the condition is true, only the first process executes the refresh method, 
    // the others wait for it to execute before proceeding to the send() method.
    if(%some_coditions%){
      manager.refresh();
    }

    client.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why not use a lock? Obtain it at the start of the method, and wrap the content in a `try/finally` to properly release it.

Comment: It is clear that lock is the main tool in this case. The question is more about how to organise a queue of requests, and after refresh is executed, continue executing send for the whole queue.

Comment: You don't, that is what automatically will happen when using `Lock`.

Comment: What if I put a lock at the TestManager.refresh() level?

That is, processes will go inside there and then return to TestService and call send()

Comment: That won't prevent from multiple calls to refresh due to the logic being checked multiple times. You wanted to block when refresh was called, so you need to lock outside of it.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for the advice. One last question though. Why are you sure that after the first process unlocks the lock - the other processes in the queue will not go to execute the same refresh method?

Or do you mean that it is possible to set some flag at TestManager level that the operation has already been performed?

Comment: That is under the assumption that the check in the if statement results in `false` then. If the refresh is a onetime only operation then why do it like this instead of at startup?